# How can I redirect all prints to a email body

Tags: python-2.7

I tried to get the prints out to a text file. I got the text file output right. Mail sending is also OK but cannot add all the print texts to email body. First thout to redirect all prints to email body. Then thought to read to output text file for the email body, failed in both.

```
import sys, os, arcpy, time
import string, smtplib
from arcpy import env

env.overwriteOutput = True

postFix = time.strftime("%Y%m%d")
LogsLocation = os.getcwd()

Script = sys.argv[0]    # This get the script name
ScriptFile = Script.split('\\')[-1]
LogFileName = ScriptFile.split('.')[0]

def listFcsInGDB():
    # set your arcpy.env.workspace to a gdb before calling
    for fds in arcpy.ListDatasets('','feature') + ['']:
        for fc in arcpy.ListFeatureClasses('','',fds):
            for Owner in OwnerList:
                if fc.split('.')[-2] == Owner:
                    yield os.path.join(fds, fc)


def SendEmail(message,Priority):
    SUBJECT = "Asset length report for Water"
    TO = email
    FROM = "AssetLength.Report@DB.production.com"
    MIMEversion = "1.0"
    ContentType = "text/html"
    BODY = string.join((
            "From: %s" % FROM,
            "To: %s" % TO,
            "Subject: %s" % SUBJECT ,
            "X-Priority: %s" % Priority ,
            "MIME-Version: %s" % MIMEversion,
            "Content-type: %s" % ContentType,
            "",
            message
            ), "\r\n")
    server = smtplib.SMTP('smtpmail',25) #server = smtplib.SMTP(HOST)
    server.sendmail(FROM, [TO], BODY)
    server.quit()


DEBUG = 1


if DEBUG:

    print '\nGenerating asset length report for -\n  Effluent, \n  Sewer and \n  Water ... ...'
    Environment = DEV
    Email = 'email'

    txt = open(LogsLocation + '\\' + postFix + '_' + LogFileName + '_' + Environment + ".txt", 'w')
    sys.stdout = txt

    print "----------------------"  # to email body
    print Script                    # to email body
    print "----------------------"  # to email body

    OwnerList = ['EFFLUENT', 'SEWER']

    if Environment == 'DEV':
        Server = 'DBRZSQL07'

    print "Input: ", Environment    # to email body

    DatabaseConnectionDirectory = r'\\xxx\ConnectionFiles'
    Workspace = env.workspace = DatabaseConnectionDirectory+ '\\' + Server + '\\' + 'Me.sde'
    #print "\nWorkspace: ", Workspace, "\n"

    print 'Effluent Network'    # to email body
    print '----------------'    # to email body

    fcs = listFcsInGDB()
    for fc in fcs:
        if fc.split('.')[-2]+'.'+fc.split('.')[-1] == 'EFFLUENT.Main':
            arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management (fc, "EMlyr")
            arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management ("EMlyr", "NEW_SELECTION", " OWNER <> 'OTHER' AND LIFECYCLESTATUS <> 'ABANDONED' ")
            Length=[]
            rows = arcpy.SearchCursor("EMlyr")
            for row in rows:
                Segment = row.getValue("SHAPE.STLength()")
                Length.append(Segment)
            total = sum(Length)
            #totalkm = sum(Length)/1000
            print 'Effluent Main ..                    ', (round(total, 2)), 'meter'    # to email body
            arcpy.Delete_management("EMlyr")


    print '\nSewer Network' # to email body
    print '--------------'  # to email body

    fcs = listFcsInGDB()
    for fc in fcs:
        if fc.split('.')[-1] == 'GravityMain':
            arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management (fc, "GMlyr")
            arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management ("GMlyr", "NEW_SELECTION", " OWNER <> 'OTHER' AND LIFECYCLESTATUS <> 'ABANDONED' ")
            Length=[]
            rows = arcpy.SearchCursor("GMlyr")
            for row in rows:
                Segment = row.getValue("SHAPE.STLength()")
                Length.append(Segment)
            total = sum(Length)
            #totalkm = sum(Length)/1000
            print 'Sewer GravityMain ..              ', (round(total, 2)), 'meter'  # to email body
            arcpy.Delete_management("GMlyr")

    print '\n***************************************************\n' # to email body

    message = message() # ??
    Priority = 3
    SendEmail(message,Priority)

else: # Bad arguments
  msg = "\nERROR>> Bad arguments."
  print msg
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass the text of the message into the function `SendEmail()` as a string. So instead of `print` statements, you need to collect all the lines you want to appear in the body of the message.

Instead of

```
print "----------------------"  # to email body
print Script                    # to email body
print "----------------------"  # to email body
```

do this

```
payload = []
...
payload.append("----------------------") 
payload.append(Script) 
payload.append("----------------------")
```

If you have more than one item in your `print` statement then you need to assemble them into a single formatted string. So instead of

```
print 'Sewer GravityMain ..              ', (round(total, 2)), 'meter'  # to email body
```

do

```
payload.append("Sewer GravityMain ..%14.2f meter" % total)
```

The list `payload` is a list of strings. Before sending, create a single string from this list with linefeeds between the elements.

```
message = '\n'.join(payload)
SendEmail(message,Priority)
```

Comment: Excellent. I was basically looking for this. Also I used '<br>' instead '\n'. '\n' doesn't break lines in email message while '<br>' does the job.

Comment: You didn't say you were displaying the email as HTML.

Comment: Sorry Boar. I thought all email message comes as html. Ignore me.

Comment: Not a problem. You worked it out anyway and that's the main thing.